# How to copy string into fixed length string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which I want to copy into a fixed length string. For example I have a `string s = "this is a string"` that is 16 characters long.

I want to copy this into a fixed length string `s2` that is 4 characters long.  So `s2` will contain `"this"`.

I also want to copy it into a fixed length string `s3` that is 20 characters long.  The end of the string will have extra spaces since the original string is only 16 characters long.

Comment: What do you consider a "fixed-length string"? A character array as in C?

Comment: Why not specify the disired interface (and usage example), so that the answers could just suggest an implementation?

Comment: A character array is an example of a fixed-length string.

Comment: Then a c-style char* without a \0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s.resize(expected_size,' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using std::string, look at `substr` to copy the first part of a string, the constructor `string(const char *s, size_t n)` to create a string of length `n` with content `s` (repeated) and `replace` to replace parts of your empty string, these will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

`substr` and `resize`/`replace` will do what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "abcdabcdabcdabcd";
    string t;
    string u;

    t = s.substr(0,4);
    u = s;
    u.resize(20, ' ');

    string v(20, ' ');
    v.replace(0, s.length(), s);

    cout << "(" << s << ")" << endl
         << "(" << t << ")" << endl
         << "(" << u << ")" << endl
         << "(" << v << ")" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something reusable you can write a couple of helper functions:

```
// Non-mutating version of string::resize
std::string resize_copy(std::string const & str, std::size_t new_sz)
{
    std::string copy = str;
    copy.resize(new_sz);
    return copy;
}

void resize_to(std::string const & str, std::string & dest)
{
    dest = resize_copy(str, dest.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "this is a string";
    std::string b(4, ' ');
    std::string c(20, ' ');
    resize_to(a, b);
    resize_to(a, c);
    std::cout << b << "|\n" << c << "|\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
this|
this is a string    |
```

Answer (score 0):

For null terminated strings, you can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

Example:

```
   char* s1 = "this is a string";
   char  s2[10];
   int   s2_size = 4;
   sprintf(s2, "%-*.*s", s2_size, s2_size, s1);
   printf("%s\n", s2);
```

`%-*.*s` format specifiers adjust string's size and add extra spaces if it's necessary.

Answer (score -1):

To handle fixed-length strings in C++, use C lib functions, such as `strncpy`.

Comment: Why the down vote? Also, fixed-length strings don't have the final '\0', it's kind of overkill using an abstraction on this case.